# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing number: G

Tags: json, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm facing the following error message while trying to convert JSON string from a HTTP response to a object:

> Error : Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing number: G. Path '', line 1, position 7.     at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadNumberCharIntoBuffer(Char currentChar, Int32 charPos)     at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadNumberIntoBuffer()     at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseNumber(ReadType readType)     at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()     at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadAndMoveToContent()     at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadForType(JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)     at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)     at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)     at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)     at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)     at Pando.DataLayer.Repositories.DBSRepository.DBSAPIint() in D:\agent_work\242\s\Application\DBS.DataLayer\Repositories\DBSRepository.cs:line 137

Here is the code I am using:

```
HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(encryptedMessage);
httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain");
var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(apiUrl, httpContent);
string responseMsg1 = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
HttpStatusCode statusCode = response.StatusCode;
string status = response.StatusCode.ToString();
int codes = ((int)response.StatusCode);
//var dataObject = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(await                      response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());  //Json is capture in dataobject
var dataObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseMsg1);  //Json is capture in dataobject
var responseCode = codes.ToString();
var Jsondata = dataObject.ToString();
 
var error1 = new SqlParameter("@errorDesc", Jsondata);
int Qryres1 = dbc.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("exec[dbo].[DBSlog] @errorDesc", error1);
//EOC 19-06-23
//var json = new SqlParameter("@json", jsonData);
//var response = new SqlParameter("@responseCode", responseCode);
var Json = new SqlParameter("@Jsondata", Jsondata);
var msgid = new SqlParameter("@msgid", od.msgId);

//var Status = new SqlParameter("@status", status);
//var Ack_type = new SqlParameter("@type", type);
//updating the status of data 
dbc.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("exec[dbo].[Usp_JsonToTable] @Jsondata @msgid", Json,msgid);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

Here is the response as show by Debug of Visual Studio:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing number: G. Path '', line 1, position 7.     at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadNumberCharIntoBuffer(Char currentChar, Int32 charPos)     at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadNumberIntoBuffer()     at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseNumber(ReadType readType)     at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()     at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadAndMoveToContent()     at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadForType(JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)     at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)     at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)     at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)     at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)     at Pando.DataLayer.Repositories.DBSRepository.DBSAPIint() in D:\agent_work\242\s\Application\DBS.DataLayer\Repositories\DBSRepository.cs:line 137

Comment: So what does `responseMsg1` contain when you set a breakpoint on `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseMsg1);`? It doesn't sound like a plaintext JSON response.

Comment: Did you had a chance to to set debugger within this method? Could exactly able to found in which line throwing the exception?

Comment: This kind of error is very straightforward. Capture the string and look at the json, it should be obvious. If you still cant find the problem, post the string here.
You can use online beautify tools if you can't see the problem at the first glance.